# Is it possible to have dozens of active connections using Bluetooth Low Energy?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot

I'm developing an app in which the smartphone should connect to a device via bluetooth. This device could be a Arduino or Raspberry Pi. When in range of this device, the smartphone should receive an ID and save it, after that, the smartphone should just inform if it is range or not. My question is what should I use in order to be possible to have dozens of active connections at the same time? I've heard about BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy), but I'm not sure if I can accomplish what I want with this. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Just scanning for and finding BLE devices is one thing and then having an "active connection" to a one is another thing. Sounds like you need to to scan for (i.e. "discover") BLE devices and recognise them based on what they broadcast (i.e. "advertise"). That is possible, is a common use case e.g. for BLE beacons and it doesn't require an "active connection" which in BLE case would mean connecting to a GATT server.

Comment: So what you are saying is that, in order to send that ID (this ID could be just a string or a number) to the smartphone I don't need an "active connection" ?

Comment: You could read about [BLE advertising](https://www.argenox.com/a-ble-advertising-primer/).

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped

Answer (score 0):

Using BLE beacons sounds like what you want to use. As mentioned, this allows you to broadcast small amounts of information without needing to connect to the device. An open format is the Eddystone Beacon that is documented at:

https://github.com/google/eddystone/blob/master/protocol-specification.md

It has four different frame types that you can use: UID, URL, TLM or EID. The UID sounds like the one that fits your requirements the best.

There are lots of tools, apps and hardware that support this format.

If you want to test your Raspberry Pi broadcasting this format, then it can be done on the command line on recent versions of the Raspberry Pi OS. Here is an example:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo btmgmt add-adv -u feaa -d 1516aafe0000112233445566778899AA112233445566 1
```

On your phone, use a generic app like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) app or [Beacon Simulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.alea.beaconsimulator) to find the beacon.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try